# cant show up my image php from a DB

Tags: php, image

the  problem is when it does return the binary file, pls help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tienda Online</title>

    <FORM action="upload_imagen.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="imagen"> Buscar imagen
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
    </FORM>

    <div id="visualizar">

    </div>

    <form action="mostrar_imagen.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="valor" >
    <input type="submit" value="mostrar">
    </form>

</html>
```

upload_imagen.php this file  upload an image and does storage in a DB

```
<?php

// Conexion a la base de datos
require "db_model.php";
class upload extends db_model {

   function whatever() {
       // Comprobamos si ha ocurrido un error.
       if (!isset($_FILES["imagen"]) || $_FILES["imagen"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Ha ocurrido un error.";
       } else {
            var_dump($_FILES["imagen"]);

            // Verificamos si el tipo de archivo es un tipo de imagen permitido.
            // y que el tamaño del archivo no exceda los 16MB
            $permitidos = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
            $limite_kb = 16384;

            if (in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'], $permitidos) && $_FILES['imagen']['size'] <= $limite_kb * 1024) {
                // Archivo temporal
                $imagen_temporal = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];

                // Tipo de archivo
                $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];

                // Leemos el contenido del archivo temporal en binario.
                $fp = fopen($imagen_temporal, 'r+b');
                $data = fread($fp, filesize($imagen_temporal));
                fclose($fp);

                //Podríamos utilizar también la siguiente instrucción en lugar de las 3 anteriores.
                // $data=file_get_contents($imagen_temporal);
                // Escapamos los caracteres para que se puedan almacenar en la base de datos correctamente.
                $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

                // Insertamos en la base de datos.
                $this->query ="INSERT INTO imagenes (imagen, tipo_imagen) VALUES ('$data', '$tipo')";
                $resultado = $this->execute_query();
                if ($resultado) {
                    echo "El archivo ha sido copiado exitosamente.";
                } else {
                    echo "Ocurrió algun error al copiar el archivo.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Formato de archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño límite de $limite_kb Kbytes.";
            }
        }
    }
}
$obj = new upload();
$obj->whatever();
?>
```

mostrar_imagen.php this section retrives the image in binary format, then i want to show it, so i read that i need a header and send it the type of image it is for example .jpg, .gif but i dont know if a i have an error

```
<?php
require 'db_model.php';
class mostrar extends db_model {

    function __construct()
    {
        $id = $_POST['valor'];
        $this->query = "SELECT imagen, tipo_imagen 
                        FROM imagenes
                        WHERE imagen_id=$id";
        $datos = $this->execute_query_as();

        $imagen = $datos['imagen']; // Datos binarios de la imagen.

        $tipo = $datos['tipo_imagen'];  // Mime Type de la imagen.

        // Mandamos las cabeceras al navegador indicando el tipo de datos que vamos a enviar.
---- > my problem is here, i guess

        header("Content-type: image/jpg");
        echo $imagen;
        // A continuación enviamos el contenido binario de la imagen.
    }
}

$obj = new mostrar();
?>
```

db_model.php

```
<?php
/**
* clase de la base de datos
*/
include_once('config.php');
class db_model 
{
    private $db_host = "localhost";
    private $db_user = "root";
    private $db_pass = "";
    protected $db_name = "tienda_cartas";
    protected $query;
    protected $rows = array();
    private $conection; 
    private function open_conection()
    {
        $this->conection = new mysqli($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);
        if ($this->conection->connect_errno) {
            echo "error al conectar";
            die();
        } else {
            echo "conectado";
        }
    }

    private function close_conection() {
        $this->conection->close();
    }

    protected function execute_query() {
        $this->open_conection();
        $result = $this->conection->query($this->query);
        if(!$result){
            echo "no se pudo ejecutar el sql";
        }
        $this->close_conection();
        return $result;
        header("location:index.php");
    }

    protected function execute_query_as() {
        $this->open_conection();
        $result = $this->conection->query($this->query);
        if(!$result){
            echo "no se pudo ejecutar el sql";
        }
        $array_as = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if(!$array_as){
            echo "no hay incidencias";
            die();
        }

        $this->close_conection();
        return $array_as;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Where is it going wrong? What does get stored on the database? MORE INFORMATION!

Comment: srry for the lack of info, i dont have any error messages, my error its located here :header("Content-type: image/jpg");
                  echo $imagen;
in the DB, the images are stored correcly, so i can download them and they are fine

Answer (score 0):

This could be your problem:

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
```

In your classes you use `mysqli_*` functions, but this one belongs to the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. When you call it it will automatically try to open a new database connection with `mysql_connect()`, which will fail because it doesn't have any information about your host. `mysql_real_escape_string()` will then return `false`:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in test.php on line 2
bool(false)
```

Just remove the line, escaping binary data will most probably ruin it anyway. Instead you should use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: first of all thank you for the aportation, i changed the line that u said, yes i was wrong with mysql::mysqli, but the error doesnt end there.. this is a app to learn i know that i need procedures to prevent sql inyections but thnx for say it.
my problem its when i try to show the image, appear an broke image icon :( i can download the images from DB and it works